# Configuring javax.servlet.Filter and javax.xml.rpc.handler.GenericHandler at server level

Tags: handler, servlet-filters

I have one Filter and few Handlers (GenericHandler), which work fine when configured per web application or web-service. I was just wondering if there is a way of configuring these at server level (at a common place) so that every web application or web service deployed in the server can have them implicitily configured so that I dont have to go to every application writing the same configuration in them. I am using websphere 6.1 server.

Thanks,
Nitin

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for the same in JBoss.

At least in Jboss and Tomcat you have a base web.xml. You can put there all the common configuration. So you can put there the common filter and the mapping for it. The class and resources of the filter will have to be in a common place. In JBoss is *`server_name`*`/lib` (typically `default/lib`).

I'm gonna try it. Hope it works!